# C++ Tree pointer Error

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, runtime-error

I am trying to figure out how to create a tree in C++. I have tried debugging this for hours and I thought it was time I got another set of eyes on it. My question is if my treeNodeClass looks correct. Right now I am getting a stack explosion because I'm double removing items from my node. The tree itself will be parsing a simple xml file. Here is my code.

`#include "treeNodeClass.h"`

```
TreeNodeClass::TreeNodeClass()
{
  cout << "TREENODECLASS::TREENODECLASS()" << endl;
  attributes.clear();
  children.clear();
  data = "";
  height = 0;
  parent = NULL;
  tag = "";
  cout << "EXIT TREENODECLASS::TREENODECLASS()" << endl;
}

TreeNodeClass::TreeNodeClass(const TreeNodeClass& other)
{
    cout << "TREENODECLASS::TREENODECLASS(const other)" << endl;
    parent = NULL; 
    CopyIntoMe(other); 
    cout << "EXIT TREENODECLASS::TREENODECLASS(const other)" << endl;
}

TreeNodeClass::~TreeNodeClass()
{
      cout << "TREENODECLASS::~TREENODECLASS()" << endl; 
      if(parent)
        delete parent;
      parent = NULL; 
      children.clear(); 
      attributes.clear();
      cout << "EXIT TREENODECLASS::~TREENODECLASS()" << endl;
}

void TreeNodeClass::CreateAttrib(string root, string val)
{
  string attrib = root + "=" + val;
  attributes.push_back(attrib);
}

void TreeNodeClass::CreateTag(string data, string name)
{
  tag = name;
  this->data = data;
}

list<string> TreeNodeClass::ReturnAttrib()
{
  return this->attributes; 
}

string TreeNodeClass::ReturnTag(string tag)
{
  string retTag = "";
  if(this->tag == tag)
    retTag = this->tag;
  return retTag;
}

void TreeNodeClass::AddChildren(TreeNodeClass* c)
{
if(c != NULL)
  children.push_back(c);
}

TreeNodeClass& TreeNodeClass::operator=(const TreeNodeClass& other)
{
cout << "TREENODECLASS& TREENODECLASS OPERATOR = " << endl;
if(&other != this)
{
  if(parent)
    delete parent;

  parent = NULL; 
  attributes.clear(); 
  children.clear(); 
  CopyIntoMe(other); 
}
return *this;
}

void TreeNodeClass::CopyIntoMe(const TreeNodeClass& other)
{
  cout << "Copy into me" << endl;
  tag = other.tag; 
  data = other.data; 
  attributes = other.attributes; 
  children = other.children; 
  parent = new TreeNodeClass; 
  parent = other.parent; 
  height = other.height; 
}


void TreeNodeClass::AddParent(TreeNodeClass* p)
{ 
  if(p)
  {
    parent = new TreeNodeClass;
    parent = p; 
  }
}

std::vector< TreeNodeClass* > TreeNodeClass::ReturnChildren()
{
  return children; 
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const TreeNodeClass& treeNode)
{
out << "NODE: " << treeNode.tag << " " << treeNode.data << endl;
out << "CHILDREN: " << treeNode.children.size() << endl;
out << "HEIGHT: " << treeNode.height << endl;
out << "Attributes: "; 
for(list<string>::const_iterator iter = treeNode.attributes.begin(); iter != treeNode.attributes.end(); iter++)
{
  out << *iter << " ";  
}
out << endl;
}

void TreeNodeClass::SetHeight(int h)
{
  height = h;
}

/*void function(TreeNodeClass* node)
{
  cout << node << " " << *node << endl; 

}

TreeNodeClass* function2(TreeNodeClass* node)
{

  return node; 
}

int main()
{
  cout << "STARTING PROGRAM" << endl;
  cout << "CREATING A TREE NODE CLASS " << endl;
  TreeNodeClass* newNode;
  TreeNodeClass* tempNode; 

  list<string> attribs; 

  newNode = new TreeNodeClass; 
  tempNode = new TreeNodeClass; 

  newNode->SetHeight(10); 

  cout << *tempNode << " " <<  *newNode << endl;
  tempNode->SetHeight(20); 

  cout << *tempNode << "\n " <<  *newNode << endl;

  cout << "Setting equal " << endl;
  *tempNode = *newNode; 
  cout << *tempNode << " " <<  *newNode << endl;

  tempNode->SetHeight(40); 
  cout << *tempNode << " " <<  *newNode << endl;

  tempNode->AddChildren(newNode); 
  newNode->AddParent(tempNode); 
  cout << *tempNode << "\n " <<  *newNode << endl;

  return 0;
}
*/
```

And I'm trying to use this code on a simple state machine. I basically set up a vector of lists to return the states. This is what I believe is giving me a majority of my errors. I've been staring at this as well for a while, but I'm kind of lost.The machine will create the tree (supposedly). When the state machine finishes (state 10) it returns and the calling function will just make another call to yylex(). Thanks for the help so far!

```
TreeNodeClass* ProcessTree(TokenT token, vector <list <stateAssoc> >& vecTree, int depth)
   {
int state = 1; //Assume this is a new record.
bool noState = false;
bool update = true;
int dex = 0;
string root, value, data, tag;
TreeNodeClass* treeNode;

treeNode = new TreeNodeClass; //Assume a new node per state machine visit.


while(state != 10)
{
  switch(state)
  {
case 1: dex = 1;
    break;

case 2: state = 3;
    noState = true;
    root = yylval;
    break;

case 3: state = 4;
    noState = true;
    break;

case 4: dex = 3;
    value = yylval;
    //cout << value << endl;
    treeNode->CreateAttrib(root, value);
    break;

case 5: dex = 2;
    data = yylval;
    //cout << 5 << " " << yylval  << " " << token << endl;

    //If its data store as data; if tag its a start tag.
    break;

case 6: dex = 4;
    //cout << token << " " << yylval << endl;
    break;

case 7: state = 9;
    noState = true;
    tag = yylval;
    //cout << tag << token << endl;
    if(data != "" and data != "authors")
      treeNode->CreateTag(data, tag);
    break;

case 8: {
      TreeNodeClass* childNode = new TreeNodeClass;
      childNode = ProcessTree(token, vecTree, depth+1);

      cout << "BEFORE PARENT" << endl;
      childNode->AddParent(treeNode);
      childNode->SetHeight(depth); 
      treeNode->AddChildren(childNode);
      delete childNode;
      childNode = NULL;
    }
    token = TokenT(yylex()); //Get a new token to process.
    dex = 5;
    break;

case 9: state = 10;
    noState = true;
    update = false;
    break;

case 10: noState = true;
    update = false;
    break;

default: cout << "Error " << endl;
    cout << state << endl;
    cin.get();
    break;

  }

  if(!noState)
state = FindMatch(vecTree[dex], token);
  else
noState = false;

  if(update)
token = TokenT(yylex());
  else
update = true;
}
return treeNode;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.A children shouldn`t delete a parent:

```
TreeNodeClass::~TreeNodeClass()
{
      cout << "TREENODECLASS::~TREENODECLASS()" << endl; 
      /* Delete next 2 lines
      if(parent)
        delete parent;
      */
      parent = NULL; 
      children.clear(); 
      attributes.clear();
      cout << "EXIT TREENODECLASS::~TREENODECLASS()" << endl;
}
```

2.Containers will not delete a pointer -- you should take it in mind always. Easy way to delete, for example:

```
 for (vector<TreeNodeClass*>::iterator child = children.begin(); child != children.end(); ++child)
     delete *child;
```

But best way -- not use native pointers and use some smart pointers or shared pointers.

3.Main function do not delete pointers `tempNode` and `newNode`.

4.If you'll use native pointers, you should recursively create and copy each children. In other way you'll catch memory leak.

5.Example of method `CopyIntoMe`:

```
void TreeNodeClass::CopyIntoMe(const TreeNodeClass& other)
{
  cout << "Copy into me" << endl;
  tag = other.tag; 
  data = other.data; 
  attributes = other.attributes; 

  // delete each pointer to Nodes
  foreach (vector<TreeNodeClass*>::iterator child = children.begin(); child != children.end(); ++child)
    delete *child;
  children.clear();

  // Copy recursively each child
  foreach (vector<TreeNodeClass*>::iterator child = other.children.begin(); child != other.children.end(); ++child) {
    TreeNodeClass* new_child = new TreeNodeClass;
    new_child->CopyIntoMe(*child);
    children.push_back(new_child);
  }

  parent = other.parent; 
  height = other.height; 
}
```

Comment: Good point. I wasn't thinking of that. I was coming from my OOP training where we just deleted all data upon destructor. This is my first time with trees, hence the problem.

Comment: The Main function was just test code. I kind of just left that part in for the spirit. Is there any easy (or correct) way to delete a container that stores several pointers? I assume I would use a delete call and then set the pointer to NULL for each n in the container.

Comment: Containers on clear call destructor for each item. In this case item at type pointer and pointer destructor not free allocated memory and not call destructor of object.

Comment: In case `state == 8` your code: create new TreeNodeClass-object, remember pointer to it and delete this object, but pointer to it save in container `children`. You should see point 2 and 4 of my answer.

Comment: I'm not able to use a smart pointer with the boost library because of system limitations. For some reason its not working. So when I add a child I should make a copy of the data in the pointer and then push that on the vector? As I was looking at it, I was taking a child, putting it in the vector and then deleting the unneeded child pointer because I assumed a copy was being placed in the vector. Was I incorrect?

Comment: In your case the best way is create node-object, push in `children` without deletion. Call delete near `children.clear()` in two places: destructor and method `CopyIntoMe`. And also you should fix method `CopyIntoMe` (I`ll write example in answer)

Comment: Getting rid of the delete in state 8 definitely helped! Before I removed that code I was receiving a double free error and a stack explosion. Now its only a seg fault which is a wee bit better. I'll keep an eye out for the revision.

Comment: The copy-constructor is incorrect -- it should remove this object from parent's children list. Example code of this written in my version of `CopyIntoMe`.

Comment: What did you mean my this object? I know that the copyintome will now take care of clearing a list and inserting new values. What more could be needed for the copy-constructor?

Comment: After taking your advice, I found my segmentation fault. I was doing the same thing with the pointers (premature deletion) after the call to processToken. After I removed that delete and let my class handle pointer deallocation, there was no problem. Thank you for all your help @Lex

Answer (score 2):

This is bad:

```
parent = new TreeNodeClass;
parent = p;
```

This is a memory leak.  Since you are allocating memory and pointing parent to it, then immediately pointing parent to something else, you can never delete that allocated memory.  The memory will be allocated and lost every time AddParent() is called.

Comment: And also in `CopyIntoMe` method.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. For some reason I forgot that the parent was in the class. If i assign parent to p that will copy the pointer only correct? (It's been a while with the pointers).

Comment: Yes it will make parent a pointer to the passed in TreeNodeClass.